# How do I put color on frame at \xymatrix?

Tags: lyx, xy-pic

I'm writing `*++[o][F-,]{3}` at `\xymatrix` for example.
How can I make that the 3 will be green and the frame at red?

And one more Q please:
How can I make the `*++[o][F-,]{3}` that will be more dark? (the inside of `*++[o][F-,]{3}` and not the frame...)

How can I make the 7 like this?
[image]

Thank you!

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\setlength{\parindent}{0bp}
\usepackage[all]{xy}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\xyR}[1]{%
\xydef@\xymatrixrowsep@{#1}
} % end of \xyR

\newcommand{\xyC}[1]{%
\xydef@\xymatrixcolsep@{#1}
} % end of \xyC

\makeatother


\begin{document}
\L{$\xymatrix{ &  & *++[o][F]{3}\ar@{-}[rd]\ar@{-}[dl]\\
 & *++[o][F]{6} &  & *++[o][F]{7}\\
\\
}
$}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It would be much easier for people to test any possible answers if you supplied a document that demonstrated these rather than have fragments that can't be processed. (This is true of almost all questions)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, An image it's OK?

Comment: No I mean tex source of a document, if you want people to test their answers (and most people don't answer without testing) you have a much bigger chance of someone answering if you supply a document from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}` and say how you want its output to change. Otherwise just making a test case is too much work.

Comment: @DavidCarlisleת Yes, but I'm using LyX, it still be useful?

Comment: well would a small tex document be useful to you _as an answer_ if so you should make one, to save everyone trying to help having to make one. especially as xypic isn't so common these days making a document that sets it up correctly makes it more likely to get an answer

Comment: @DavidCarlisleת I hope it's good :-) If not tell me.  Thank you and sorry for the delay...

Comment: not bad thanks:-) I simplified it a bit more, otherwise it tried to load hebrew fonts I didn't have.

Comment: Do you know tikz-cd? Would you be willing to use another simpler package for such stuff?

Comment: Color is not supported by Xy-pic with the PDF driver, only with the `dvips` driver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the color extension of XY-pic.

1. Import xcolor package and add color option to xy package:
   \usepackage{xcolor}
   \usepackage[all,color]{xy}
2. Use modifiers of format: [F*:*colorname*]. Here are some examples:
   a) Gray background: *++[o][F*:gray]{1}
   b) Gray background + emphasised boundary (default: black): *++[o][F**:gray]{1}
   c) Gray background + Red boundary: *++[o][F-:red][F*:gray]{1}
   d) Overlapping frames: *++[o][F*:red]++[F*:gray]{1}

[image]

The solution to your question:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\setlength{\parindent}{0bp}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[all,color]{xy}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\xyR}[1]{%
\xydef@\xymatrixrowsep@{#1}
} % end of \xyR

\newcommand{\xyC}[1]{%
\xydef@\xymatrixcolsep@{#1}
} % end of \xyC

\makeatother


\begin{document}

\L{$\xymatrix{ &  & *++[o][F]{3}\ar@{-}[rd]\ar@{-}[dl]\\
 & *++[o][F]{6} &  & *++[o][F**:lightgray]{7}\\
\\
}
$}
\end{document}
```

The output is as follows.
[image]

For more details, see [xypdf on CTAN](http://ctan.math.utah.edu/ctan/tex-archive/macros/generic/diagrams/xypic/doc/xypdf.pdf).

Answer (score 4):

There may be a more "native" xypic way but I didn't see anything about fill styles with a quick look at the manual. You can however not draw the frames with xy then draw framed/filled nodes with anything else, pstricks, tikz, or as here, picture mode

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\setlength{\parindent}{0bp}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\usepackage{color,pict2e}
\newcommand\cfill[2]{%
\begin{picture}(0,0)%
\put(0,0){{\color[gray]{#1}\circle*{18}}}%
\put(0,0){{\circle{18}}}%
\put(0,0){\makebox(0,0){#2}}%
\end{picture}}



%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\xyR}[1]{%
\xydef@\xymatrixrowsep@{#1}
} % end of \xyR

\newcommand{\xyC}[1]{%
\xydef@\xymatrixcolsep@{#1}
} % end of \xyC

\makeatother


\begin{document}
\L{$\xymatrix{ &  & 
*++{\color{red}\cfill{1}{\textcolor{green}{3}}}\ar@{-}[rd]\ar@{-}[dl]\\
 & *++[o][F]{6} &  & *++{\cfill{.9}{7}}\\
\\
}
$}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you explain me more please about what you added? What is the meaning of '\put(0,0){{\color[gray]{#1}\circle*{18}}}'? Thank you!

Comment: And why do use the number 2 at: \newcommand\cfill[2] ??  Thank you so much!!

Comment: @Yoar the command has two arguments: the fill colour and the text content

Comment: @Yoar `\put` is a standard latex command (it does not need any package) to put text at a specified coordinate. `pict2e` just makes the command use postscript/pdf drawing at the back to get nicer circles and lines than the original version, which uses special latex drawing fonts.

Comment: And what is the #1? Thank you so much David!!

Comment: @Yoar It's the colour using the `{gray}` colour model so 1=white 0=black and .9 as used above is light grey

Comment: Thank you! and 18 is the size of the circle? The radius is 18pt?

Comment: BTW - Why I'm getting error when I tried to change the color? e.g. I put black and I get error...

Comment: @Yoar as written it takes a numeric argument between 0 and 1 as the definition has `\color[gray]{#1}` you could change it to `\color{#1}` then it would take a defined colour name so you would need to change `\cfill{1}` to `\cfill{white}` and `\cfill{.9}` to `\cfill{mygray}` and use \definecolor to define `mygray`. but could then use red or any other colour you wanted (but it is best not to ask new questions in comments, the system is warning about the length of this thread already)

Comment: Yes, I know, but I try to change at the preamble `\put(0,0){{\color[gray]{#1}\circle*{50}}}` from gray to black for example. Why it doesn't work??

Answer (score 0):

As a reminder, the `*++[o][F:red]{3}` will draw text 3 surrounded by red circle frame.
Do remember to include `\usepackage{color}` and `\xyoption{color}` at the head of your tex file.